# Cannot find proper library when creating module on samsung s3 with card io

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, card.io

does card.io work on samsung s3?

i keep getting an error saying it cannot find the proper library.

I have followed the instructions listed on the website and placed the files in the proper directory

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The card.io scan SDK has been tested on the Samsung Galaxy S3.

Usually a library load error means that Android cannot find one of the native libraries. Make sure that the following files exist with this exact path in your project:

```
libs/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so
libs/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so
libs/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2
libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so
libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so
```

Additionally, to maintain graceful failover for unsupported devices, ensure that

```
libs/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so
libs/x86/libcardioDecider.so
libs/mips/libcardioDecider.so
```

are also present.

The zip file you downloaded from the card.io website is designed to be expanded into the root directory of your project, and should put all of the files where you need them.

Also, as a sanity check, you can clone the example project from `git@github.com:card-io/android-scan-demo.git`. Note that you'll need to go into the example app and paste in your app token.

Comment: Am using card.io credit card scanner library. Am running the sample they have given. But it never succeed the scanning process. Still blinking only happen. Am scanning HDFC Bank MasterCard. I have followed the integration step provided in the https://www.card.io/integrate/android. I don't know why the scanning process is not succeeded? card.io experts could please help me in that.